# Designing a high-power PCB

Tags: power, pcb, pcb-design, high-current, high-power

I'm trying to build a Raspberry Pi cluster (at least 32 Pi's) and I need a convenient way to power them all. So I'd like to design a power distribution board. The distribution board will have USB power ports for each Pi and it will be controlled by an Atmel microcontroller.

I currently have a 350W 5V supply, which can safely supply a hefty 60A. Assuming that each Pi will draw between 800mA and 1A, I should have more than enough power.

With that said, as a new engineer (who specializes in digital electronics), I've only designed one PCB before. I've never done anything with high power before. What design considerations should I take into account when designing the PCB?

I've done a little bit of research and everything seems to point to [using a PCB bus bar](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59735/creating-a-high-current-bus-on-a-pcb) to carry the high current. I would then branch off the bus to each individual Pi. The other option is to use a high power connector [like this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/0760010110/WM4670-ND/2573777). I'm kind of leaning towards the latter.

With that said I should also probably provide some level protection circuitry for the Pi's in case of a power surge (although my supply, a [Cotek AK-350-05](http://www.kepcopower.com/ak.htm), should be able to provide a fair amount of protection itself). I was thinking of placing a 1.5A PTC in series with each USB port.

Are there any other things I should consider? Thanks

Comment: Depending on which type of Raspberry Pi you are going to use, you might need to account for higher maximum A's per Pi. I'm easily able to power "normal" B and B+ Pi's from a 1.5A rated power supply, but had to switch to a 2.2A rated powersupply for my rPi 2 B+'s. So your 800mA-1A range might not be sufficient, and you might need to count on 1.5A-2A per Pi (at least during startup and processing peaks).

Comment: Hmm, that could be an issue. I'm using R Pi 2's

Comment: Note that my findings are WITH a usb keyboard/mouse combo and an Edimax WiFi dongle plugged in, as well as a monitor. If you plan to run this setup as an ethernet-only, no USB devices computing cluster the max Amps might be much different. I'd do some measurements on a single Pi just to figure out what you're dealing with.

Comment: Yea, I'm only gonna be using ethernet and ssh. The USB ports will not be used

Answer (score 5):

Consider also a distributed approach with point-of-load (POL) converters.  The idea is that you distribute power across the board at lower current and higher voltage.  Presently, you are thinking about having one AD/DC converter which outputs 5V 32A which goes directly to RPis.  You could have an AC/DC which outputs 48V 3.5A.  Each RPi has a dedicated DC-DC buck converter (the POL converter), which generates 5V 1A from 48V.  This way, you are only dealing with more manageable 3.5A and 1A currents on your board.

[image]
([Source](http://www.cotsjournalonline.com/articles/view/100746) of the diagram.)

Answer (score 2):

I've worked on PCB-based bus bars before (over 1kW total power) and we were able to get by with just a PCB, no external bus bars.

Here are some of the things to consider:

- Copper thickness: use 2oz / 70um (or greater) copper for your PCB.
- Add solder islands to further increase current carrying capability. [[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gy1K3ayPfOk)] [[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9q5vwCESEQ)]
- Calculate the temperature rise and add forced cooling if necessary.

Here's a quick example calculation using the Saturn PCB Toolkit:

[image: Conductor Properties]